# Python code to check if a filename is present in a text file

Tags: python

I am new in python, the requirement is like i have one flat file where it mentioned 3 files name, i need to check the file name written in flat file it exist in directory or not.
Below mentioned is my code. but everytime it showing me file doesnt exist where as file present.

my flatfile name is filename.txt. where i have 3 entry

- TEST-WMS-0132-EN2-006.tar
- TEST-WMS-0132-EN2-004.tar
- TEST-WMS-0132-EN2-005.tar

I need to read file name line by line and check the file present in directory or not. but i am not sure why this code is not working. flat file as well as 3 file present in same directory

```
with open('filename.txt','r') as f:
    line = f.readlines()
    print(line)
    for fh in line:
        print(fh)
        if path.exists(fh):
            print (fh,"File exist")
        else:
            print (fh,"File not exist")
            sys.exit(0)
```

Comment: Is not working how?

Comment: why do you call a collection of lines `line`?

Comment: its just variable name

Answer (score 4):

That is because `readlines` *includes the trailing newline* character.

So you need to strip it manually (generally using `str.strip` or `str.rstrip` for more safety) as your filenames likely don't include a newline.

That aside, `readlines` isn't really necessary here, you can just iterate on the file directly. However, you *really* should provide an explicit encoding to `open` when using it in text mode, otherwise it uses whatever garbage `locale.getpreferredencoding(False)` returns and that is often not what you want (especially on windows systems).

Comment: in addition, you may mention that if one file does not exists the script will exit (and not check the rest) due to call `sys.exit()`. which is generally not necessary anyway

Answer (score 0):

The code below will create a dict where the file name points to a boolean telling if the file exists or not.

```
from os import path
with open('filename.txt','r') as f:
    file_names = [l.strip() for l in f.readlines()]
    exists = {fn: path.exists(fn) for fn in file_names}
```